# JSON flattening and mapping to the corresponding records using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where customer and their ids are coming as part of json in the below format and need to flatten them and get rows where each customer id is corresponding to the customer.

I tried but unable to achieve this requirement, if anyone can help me here?

**Input JSON:**

```
{
"data":{
    "cust_name":["cust_1","cust_2","cust_3","cust_4","cust_5"],
    "cust_id":[1,2,3,4,5]
    }
}
```

**Expected Output from Spark:**

```
-------------------------------
| customer_id | customer_name |
-------------------------------
|     1       |    cust_1     |
|     2       |    cust_2     |
|     3       |    cust_3     |
|     4       |    cust_4     |
|     5       |    cust_5     |
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you read this json in data frame, I suppose you may use something like this:

```
(df
 .withColumn("customer_merged", arrays_zip("data.cust_id", "data.cust_name")
 .withColumn("customer_merged", explode("customer_merged"))
 .select("customer_merged.*")
)
```

`arrays_zip` will create new column containing struct of merged columns, while `explode` will expand array to rows.